# ReactJS throws "map" is not defined Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapping, searchkit

I am not very familiar with JavaScript, but have to implement a table in ReactJS for my current project. At the part bellow I get an `error: map is not defined`. I have done some Error-Research but could not find an satisfying answer here or on Google.

```
   render() {
        const { hits } = this.props
        return (
            <div style={{width: '100%', boxSizing: 'border-box', padding: 8}}>
                <table className="sk-table sk-table-striped" style={{width: '100%', boxSizing: 'border-box'}}>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th>Author</th>
                            <th>Keywords</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
            {map(hits, hit => (
              <tr key={hit._id}>
                <td>{hit._source.title}</td>
                <td>{hit._source.year}</td>
                <td>{hit._source.imdbRating}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is an array method, so you want to invoke it on your array and give a function as argument that should be executed for every element in the array. `hits.map(hit => ...)`

Comment: Thank you very much! Helped instantly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the map function on the hits const you create at the top. Like this:

```
{hits.map(hit => (
  <tr key={hit._id}>
    <td>{hit._source.title}</td>
    <td>{hit._source.year}</td>
    <td>{hit._source.imdbRating}</td>
  </tr>
))}
```

Answer (score 1):

map is a function defined on the Array prototype in javascript. You are calling map here on the global object, which does not have that method defined. Thus, you get an undefined error.

hits.map is probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Is your example  from http://docs.searchkit.co/v2.0.0/components/basics/hits.html

In this case You need declare map ... 
Put :

```
import { map } from 'lodash'
```

at begining of your file , after import {....} from 'searchkit'